# Separate characher end if

Tags: r

I was coding on R and I will find a code that separates if the text in column b finishes with SX o DX. The final part (SX DX) must be maintained and add in a new column

```
a = read.table(text="
Num X b   
12   3   "ab SX"    
13   35  "sd DX" 
14   35  "dh af SX" 
15   10  "sd"",h=T)

Result = read.table(text="
Num X b DXSX  
12   3   "ab"  SX    
13   35  "sd" DX 
14   35  "dh af"  SX 
15   10  "sd"  0",h=T)
```

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have tried with grepl but I don't work and the solution is not what I want

Comment: But *what* did you try exactly? What does it mean that it didn't work? Anybody posting an answer is left just guessing as to what the problem is without any more information in the question than this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(a, b, into = c("b", "DXSX"), sep = "\\s+(?=[A-Z]{2})", fill = "right")
```

-output

```
Num  X     b DXSX
1  12  3    ab   SX
2  13 35    sd   DX
3  14 35 dh af   SX
4  15 10    sd <NA>
```

#### data

```
a <- structure(list(Num = c(12, 13, 14, 15), X = c(3, 35, 35, 10), 
    b = c("ab SX", "sd DX", "dh af SX", "sd")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Can you explain the sep? Because my original dataset is a little different and I would try to adapt.. For example in column b I have "Luc CR-HI" and the code separate this phrase. Thanks!

Comment: @Inuraghe the `sep` is based on the pattern I found in your example. i.e. split at one or more space (`\\s+`) that precedes two upper case character (`[A-Z]{2}`).  So if you have `Luc CR-HI`, it splits between Luc and CR i.e. `CR-HI` will be in last column DXSX.  What is your expected here

Comment: Yes, I know the split is in another place.. I would like to find a solution that resolves the problem for each different situation, this is why I ask  to explain me sep.. I didn't find a solution myself. Also using sep=DX I can't resolve it. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Inuraghe For the Luc CR-HI, do you want `luc CR` and `HI` separated?

Comment: Nope, I want only DX and SX in column DXSX the other information I would like that remain in the column b

Comment: @Inuraghe so that would be `NA`?  Sorry, I didn't understand.  Perhaps, `separate(a, b, into = c("b", "DXSX"), sep = "\\s+(?=(DX|SX))", fill = "right")` or `extract(a, b, into = c("b", "DXSX"), "(.*)\\s+(DX|SX)$")`